# C++: Append string to output of first and last array index in loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried to word the title as best as I could. Here I have a function that indexes through two parallel arrays and then outputs them with some formatting.

```
void outputTable(string salsa_jars[], int jars_sold[], int index[])
{
   int totalSold = 0;
   cout << setw(8) << "\nSalsa type sells: " << endl
        << "-------------------------------" << endl;

   for(int i = 0; i <= (SALSA_TYPES-1); i++)
   {
    totalSold += jars_sold[index[i]];
    cout << setw(15) << left << salsa_jars[index[i]]
         << setw(15) << right << jars_sold[index[i]] << endl;
   }

   cout << "-------------------------------" << endl
        << "Total sales: " << setw(17) << totalSold << endl;
}
```

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to add a string to the first and last outputs of the array. Below is my attempt.

```
void outputTable(string salsa_jars[], int jars_sold[], int index[])
{
   int totalSold = 0;
   cout << setw(8) << "\nSalsa type sells: " << endl
        << "-------------------------------" << endl;

   for(int i=0;i<=(SALSA_TYPES-1);i++)
   {
      if(i == 0){
      cout << setw(7) << left << salsa_jars[index[i]]
           << "(Highest)" << setw(14) << right
           << jars_sold[index[i]] << endl;
      }
      else if (i == (SALSA_TYPES-1)){
        cout << setw(7) << left << salsa_jars[index[i]]
        << "(Lowest)" << setw(15) << right
        << jars_sold[index[i]] << endl;
      }
      else{
        totalSold += jars_sold[index[i]];
        cout << setw(15) << left << salsa_jars[index[i]]
             << setw(15) << right << jars_sold[index[i]] << endl;
      }
    }  

    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl
         << "Total sales: " << setw(17) << totalSold << endl;
}
```

[image]

But the code seems redundant, and I couldn't think of any other way to do it. If anyone has any pointers, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepare appropriate title for entry, and use common logic for displaying it:

```
for(int i=0;i<=(SALSA_TYPES-1);i++)
{
   string title = toString(salsa_jars[index[i]]);
   if(i == 0){
       title += " (Highest)";
   }
   else if (i == (SALSA_TYPES-1)){
     title += " (Lowest)";
   }
     totalSold += jars_sold[index[i]];
     cout << setw(15) << left << title
          << setw(15) << right << jars_sold[index[i]] << endl;
   }
 }
```